# Checking if an optional Vim feature is available, using Vim script

Tags: vim

I am using the same Vim configuration on several computers. They are running different Vim builds, and i do not have root access. I therefore want to check for feature support inside vimrc, so that i can avoid running unsupported plugins.

Is there a way to check if an optional Vim feature is supported from inside a Vim script? In the case i ran into, i want to detect the relatively new float support.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
:h has
:h feature-list
if has('float')
```